# What does classical theory predict about compton effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

I am currently studying Quantum Physics by Stephen Gasiorowicz. In the first chapter where he describes about compton effect, he says that

> According to classical theory, the mechanism for effect is re-radiation of light by electrons set into forced Oscillations by incident radiation, and this leads to prediction of intensity observed at angle θ that varies as $(1+\cos^2(θ))$.

Why does it vary as $(1+\cos^2(θ))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gasiorowicz is almost definitely referring to **Thomson scattering**, which is described by Wikipedia as:

> the elastic scattering of electromagnetic radiation by a free charged particle, as described by classical electromagnetism.

As for *why* Thomson scattering has that particular angular component, you are essentially asking for a derivation of Thomson scattering, which is available in the course notes of many mid-level electromagnetism courses, for example here: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/Electromagnetism/node107.html.